# Share game result with image to Facebook feed/profile?

Tags: android

Im trying to share the game result from my Tic Tac Toe app to Facebook.
This is the method i have so far:

```
public void share(String playerName, int wins) {
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:title", "Tic Tac Toe")
            .putString("og:description", "" + playerName + " now has " + wins + " wins in Tic Tac Toe." + "")
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("games.plays")
            .putObject("game", object)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("game")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(this, content);
}
```

It works, but it does not share the result in the feed or on my profile, like i see other apps are doing. It only shares it to the activity log at Facebook. Also i would like to add an image to the post. I have been looking at numerous examples but it seems like they are all outdated and are using deprecated methods.

Would anyone care to help?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete detail of sharing data on fb wall:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android